# a good night's sleep (which one is modified by "good"?)

Tags: modifiers

> a good night's sleep

Does good modify night or sleep?

The phrase means 'a sound sleep' and wonder which thing is modified by 'good'.

Comment: Good modifies the phrase "night's sleep".

Comment: In other words, it modifies "sleep", since "sleep" is the head word in the phrase "night's sleep".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a similar example, consider "a hard day's work."

FeliniusRex is right; "a day's work" is already a phrase in itself, as in "He's never done a day's work in his life." It could be expanded to "a day's [worth of] work," or "the work of a day."

So, adding the adjective "hard" into the expanded forms, they would be "a day's worth of *hard* work" or "the *hard* work of a day."